# Pivot Table in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pivot-table

I am pretty new to Python and hence I need your help on the following:

I have two tables (dataframes):

Table 1 has all the data and it looks like that:

[image: Table1]

GenDate column has the generation day.
Date column has dates.
Column D and onwards has different values

I also have the following table:

[image: Table 2]

Column I has "keywords" that can be found in the header of Table 1
Column K has dates that should be in column C of table 1

My goal is to produce a table like the following:

[image: Table 3]

I have omitted a few columns for Illustration purposes.

Every column on table 1 should be split base on the Type that is written on the Header.

Ex. A_Weeks: The Weeks corresponds to 3 Splits, Week1, Week2 and Week3

Each one of these slits has a specific Date.

in the new table, 3 columns should be created, using A_ and then the split name:

A_Week1, A_Week2 and A_Week3.

for each one of these columns, the value that corresponds to the Date of each split should be used.

I hope the explanation is good.

Thanks

Comment: Check out `pd.pivot_table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired table with the following code (follow comments and check panda api reference to learn about functions used):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# initial data
t_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'GenDate': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
     'Date': [10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30],
     'A_Days': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
     'B_Days': [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
     'A_Weeks': [110, 120, 130, 140, np.NaN, 160],
     'B_Weeks': [210, 220, 230, 240, np.NaN, 260]})
# initial data
t_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Type': ['Days', 'Days', 'Days', 'Weeks', 'Weeks'],
     'Split': ['Day1', 'Day2', 'Day3', 'Week1', 'Week2'],
     'Date': [10, 20, 30, 10, 30]})

# create multiindex
t_1 = t_1.set_index(['GenDate', 'Date'])
# pivot 'Date' level of MultiIndex - unstack it from index to columns
# and drop columns with all NaN values
tt_1 = t_1.unstack().dropna(axis=1)

# tt_1 is what you need with multi-level column labels

# map to rename columns
t_2 = t_2.set_index(['Type'])
mapping = {
    type_: dict(zip(
        t_2.loc[type_, :].loc[:, 'Date'],
        t_2.loc[type_, :].loc[:, 'Split']))
    for type_ in t_2.index.unique()}

# new column names
new_columns = list()
for letter_type, date in tt_1.columns.values:
    letter, type_ = letter_type.split('_')
    new_columns.append('{}_{}'.format(letter, mapping[type_][date]))

tt_1.columns = new_columns
```